# QML Rectangle customisation

Tags: qt, qml

If I have two Rectangles side-by-side, and I want to position an object (text or numbers) at specific points within each rectangle, can I use the pixels taken from the size as a positioner?

In this example the Rectangles are `width:100 height:100`,

What I would like to do is place my first object at `width: 2` and `height: 2`, and another object at `width: 23`, `height: 23`

**My Question Is**

Can I use the pixel size of a `Rectangle` to position children of it?

[image]

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, what do you want to do?

Comment: each rectangle has a width and height of 100 pixels, Can I use the pixel size of a Rectangle to position children of it? i.e at`width:5 height:5` i want a text and at `width :23 height :23` i want another text and so on

Comment: The position of a child item is always relative to the parent, for example in the following code: `Rectangle{ width: 100; height: 100; color: "yellow"; Rectangle{x: 5; y:5; color: "blue"} }` the blue rectangle will have the position (5, 5) with respect to the yellow rectangle.

Comment: I still do not understand your question. Do you want to place a text in the position (5, 5) with respect to a rectangle?

Comment: i think i got the answer from both Ldweller and you

Comment: If you want to create many Rectangles do not use what @Ldweller signal since those are positioners, that is, you can not provide a specific position, instead use a Repeater with a model.

Comment: It seems that you are a beginner in QML (of what I understood of your question) so I recommend you read: https://qmlbook.github.io/

Comment: to answer your question, let me explain, i want to divide rectangle's `100 pixels` into non-equal parts say i want to divide them into 18 parts and each of them will have different text. `x:1 y:1` will have first text `x:1 y:6.7` will have second text and like this there will be 18 texts

Comment: would you mind sharing some urls that would explain me more about models?

Comment: 6 pixels for a text, is not very little ?, well, if so, then use GridView

Comment: docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html

Comment: As a last point your question is not clear (I am referring to the post, in your last comments I understood your question) IMHO it seems that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), instead of asking: *i want to divide rectangle's ...* these asking about a possible solution that nobody guarantees that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question fully, you want to set one or more items(text/numbers ect) at certain points within a rectangle? 
Personally I am unsure if this is possible?!, see the link for all members of QML Item/Rectangle;

[Item QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childrenRect.x-prop)

Without knowing your use-case, if I wanted to add multiple items within a rectangle, I would use either a `Grid`,`Row` or `Column` for adding multiple objects to a rectangle, I have linked below for each of them. Please remember these are just positioners (as with eyllanesc comments) if there is specific place you want them too be, use a Repeater with a model (also linked) and for what use? Let me know if that's the case and I might be able to help a little more!

- [QML Grid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-grid.html)
- [QML Row](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.htm)
- [QML Column](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html)
- [QML Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html)

Thanks!